# Liferay Service Builder - FinderImpl between date

Tags: liferay-6

using the Liferay 6.0.6 ServiceBuilder i am trying to implement a finder method.
I want the method to return all objects whose create date is in between a given date range.

I have learned that hibernate offers the criteria `Expression.between("date", dateFrom, dateTo)`.

Howerver `com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.SQLQuery` which i use does not offer a criteria like this.

Maybe i have missed something in the service.xml already but the only thing i found here was
`<finder-column name="createDate" comparator=""/>` which is in my opinion not helpfull.

Is there a different way to implement this finder method as i want to / change the service.xml?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

further investigations brought me to
`RestrictionsFactoryUtil.between("deleteDate", dateFrom, dateTo);                                                       DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Test.class).add(criterion)`
 So there is a working criterion ;)